# AI scripting in Unity. Blocking Y rotation in code

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a game where the world is 3D yet the characters are 2D. This means that my Y rotation must not change or else the 2D sprite rotates. I have a been scripting an AI and while the enemy does attract towards my player, he also rotates by 90 degrees. How can I modify my code to make it so that the sprite follows my player in the X and Z axis but the Y axis rotation stays zero.

```cs
//CODE STARTS

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AISimple : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    float distancefrom_player;
    public float look_range = 20.0f;
    public float agro_range = 10.0f;
    public float move_speed = 5.0f;
    public float damping = 6.0f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        distancefrom_player = Vector3.Distance(player.position, transform.position);

        if (distancefrom_player < look_range)
        {
            lookAt();
        }

        if (distancefrom_player < agro_range)

        {
            attack();
        }
    }

    void lookAt()
    {
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
    }

    void attack()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * move_speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: var direction = player.position - transform.position;
direction.y = 0f;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - transform.position);

Comment: Do you mean you are always keeping the camera at the same angle? Could you show your setup with a screenshot to clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

rigidbody has this functionality, if you tick freeze y rotation you'll be fine

Comment: I've already done that. I froze the Y rotation by applying rigidbody but it follows my player with a 90 degree Y rotation when I want it to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

okay, then try to modify y rotation before you set it

```
    void lookAt()
    {
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - transform.position);
        var euler = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping).eulerAngles;
        euler.y = 0f;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(euler);
    }
```